# Java : creating a directory fails

Tags: java, file-io

I have a following code in test

```
public class TestMe {
  private static final String BACKUP_DIR_PATH = "~/backup";

  @Test
  public static void createBackupDir() throws IOException {
    File path = new File(BACKUP_DIR_PATH + "/" + getFolderName()).getCanonicalFile();
    System.out.println(path.mkdirs());
  }

  // returns 2012-07-23
  private static String getFolderName() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date).toString();
  }
}
```

When I run this test it returns `false`

Both `backup` and `2012-07-23` folder **does not exists**

What is incorrect here?

Comment: have you checked the user running the jar has enough permissions to create folders there?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x+ 64 me  staff  2176 Jul 23 13:32 me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably because Java doesn't know what the `~` means.

The `~` is a shell expansion, not a valid pathname.

Comment: How can I make java understand about ~?

Comment: @daydreamer You'd have to manual enter the path of your home directory, replacing the `~`. Or if you are running this from your home directory, you can give it a relative path like `./`

Comment: ~ is equivalent to `System.getProperty("user.home")`

Comment: @daydreamer See justderb's comment.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 private static final File HOME_DIR = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
 private static final File BACKUP_DIR = new File(HOME_DIR, "backup");
```

and go from there. In general, it's better to avoid constructing paths by appending strings like you are doing. Use the `File` methods instead to construct your path.

Note that retrieving the user's home directory property is subject to approval by any installed security manager, so your code should be prepared to handle a `SecurityException`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it on a windows system.?  If so consider using File.separator instead of "/" so the code is platform independent.

Also use System.getProperty("user.home")) instead of "~" to make it platform independent.

Comment: I am running on Mac, its because Java doesn't recognizes ~

Comment: Ok, you'd still be safer using File.seperator, or the other File methods Ted mentioned above.